# Transforming data frame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, transform, reindex

I have a situation where I have the following dataset:

```
ID      A     B    C
1      aa     -    -
2      -      bb   -
3      -      -    cc
4      aaa    -    -
```

that should be transformed to the following data frame:

```
ID    A
 1    aa
 2    bb
 3    cc
 4    aa
```

So essentially shifting rows so that it fits to the first column

Comment: The fourth item in result is 'aaa' or just 'aa' ?

Comment: Is it `df.ffill(1)`?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248185/pandas-combining-sparse-columns-in-dataframe/62249168#62249168

Comment: @Subbireddydwarampudi: just aa. these are just the dummy entries.. the only thing I want is to shift everything back to the first column.

Comment: similar to what @QuangHoang said `df.set_index('ID').replace('-',np.nan).bfill(1).iloc[:,0].reset_index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `bfill` with axis along columns after `replace` the symbol '-' by nan:

```
df_ = df.replace('-', np.nan).bfill(1)[['ID', 'A']]
print(df_)
  ID    A
0  1   aa
1  2   bb
2  3   cc
3  4  aaa
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `df.replace` to replace `-` with np.nan and set `'ID'` as index then `df.stack` and `df.droplevel`

```
df.replace('-',np.nan).set_index('ID').stack().droplevel(1)

ID
1     aa
2     bb
3     cc
4    aaa
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.at[i, 'A'] == '-':
        if df.at[i, 'B'] == '-':
            df.at[i, 'A'] = df.at[i, 'C']
        else:
            df.at[i, 'A'] = df.at[i, 'B']

df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1, inplace = True)
```

Just using nested-if statements to find the column in which we have something other than `-` and assigning that value to the value in column `A`.

```py
**Output** : df

    ID  A
0   1   aa
1   2   bb
2   3   cc
3   4   aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df.replace('-', np.nan, inplace=True)
df['new'] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(
    lambda x: ''.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1
)
df = df[['ID', 'new']]
print(df)
```

**Ouput:**

```
   ID  new
0   1   aa
1   2   bb
2   3   cc
3   4  aaa
```