# How to combine two rows in single row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I Have an Excel sheet with data arranged in this manner [image: Excel sheet merge two rows]

and I want it to be like this

[image]

Comment: I hope those aren't real people's emails

Comment: It isn't  Sir. @EdgarRamírezMondragón

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas combining sparse columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248185/pandas-combining-sparse-columns-in-dataframe)

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62452340/transforming-data-frame-in-python/62452804#62452804

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions. Do not provide images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will have to iterate through rows and columns to select out the non-empty cells. Here is a simplified version of your table.

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame({
'em':['em1','em2','em3','em1','em2','em3'],
'a':['a1','a2','a3','','',' '],
'b':['','','','b1','b2','b3']
})
print(df)
df2 =pd.DataFrame()
for em in set(df['em']):
    df_em = df[df['em']==em]
    df2 = df2.append(df_em.iloc[[0]], ignore_index = True)
    for c in range(len(df.columns)):
        if df_em.iat[0,c].strip() == '':                    
            df2.iat[len(df2)-1,c] = df_em.iat[1,c]
        else:
            df2.iat[len(df2)-1,c] = df_em.iat[0,c]
                
print('\n\n',df2)
```

Output:

```
    em   a   b
0  em1  a1
1  em2  a2
2  em3  a3
3  em1      b1
4  em2      b2
5  em3      b3


    em   a   b
0  em1  a1  b1
1  em2  a2  b2
2  em3  a3  b3
```

Answer (score -1):

If your `Name` and `Email` and `Subject` columns are equal for matching rows and you know the indices of the row groups you want to "coalesce", you can try the following steps:

1. Make those 3 columns the index of your dataframe.
2. Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to fill the null values from a different row group.

In your case the row groups are the first three and the last three.

```py
new_df = df.set_index(["Name", "Email", "Subject"])

# Combine first 3 rows with last 3
combined = new_df.iloc[:3].combine_first(new_df.iloc[3:])
```

Result:

```
                                            Q.1 Q.2 Q.3 Q.4 Q.5 Q.6 Q.7 Q.8
Name       Email                    Subject                                
MOHD AQUIL aquilchoudhary@gmail.com History   B   C   B   A   B   A   B   D
Shweta     Rangarishweta@gmail.co   History   B   A   B   D   B   C   B   A
Suraj      surajdas112@gmail.com    History   B   A   B   B   B   A   B   B
```